# value is already defined in scope in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I was trying something with the coding part in kafka streams which is shown below

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> textlines = builder.stream("iostatin2");
KStream<String, String> mstream = textlines
                .mapValues(value -> value.replace("[","" ) )
                .mapValues(value -> value.replace("]","" ) )
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll("\":\"", "\":"))
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll("\":", "\":\""))
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll("\",\"", ",\""))
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll(",\"", "\",\""))
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll(":\"\\{", ":\\{"))
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll("\\}\",", "\\},"))
                .mapValues(value -> value.replaceAll("\\},\\{" ,"\\}\\},\\{\\{"));

        textlines.foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>() {
                     @Override
                     public void apply(String key, String value) {
                         try {
                             textlines.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\},\\{")));

                             Thread.sleep(2000);
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }

                     }
                 });
```

so in the foreachaction() function

```
textlines.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\},\\{")));
```

in this line value is causing an error like variable 'value' is already defined in the scope. So what should I replace that line with...plzz help me out..

Comment: Just rename the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

value is already used as a parameter in apply() method above,
So change value in the line 
`textlines.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.split("\\},\\{")));`

to any other name like v

`textlines.flatMapValues(v -> Arrays.asList(v.split("\\},\\{")));`